# Riemann integral of non-negative continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: continuity, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Everyone might get used to the following question in the context when $f$ is assumed to be Lebesgue integrable function. In this problem, we give new hypotheses

**Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative continuous function   satisfying $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx<\infty.$ Then prove that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx=0.$$**

I have been thinking about mimicking the idea of proof from $f$ being Lebesgue integrable function. To me, it does not seem work successfully. Without applying knowledge from Lebesgue integration, how does everyone tackle the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finitenss of the improper Riemann integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ implies that given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $\Delta$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{-\Delta} f(x)dx <\epsilon$ and $\int_{\Delta}^{\infty} f(x)dx<\epsilon$. For $|h| <1$ the function $f(x+h)-f(x)$ vanishes for $|x| >\Delta +1$. Hence $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx=\int_{-\Delta-1}^{\Delta +1} |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx$. By uniform continuity of $f$ ( on $[-\Delta -2, \Delta +2]$) we can choose $\delta >0$ such that $|h|<\delta$ implies $|f(x+h)-f(x)|<\frac {\epsilon} {2\Delta +2}$ whenever $x \in [-\Delta -1,\Delta +1]$. Hence  $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx<3\epsilon$ for $|h| <\delta$.

Comment: This is a proof not using any Lebesgue Theory. As pointed out by RRL this result is trivial if we use the corresponding result for Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: I can buy that $f(x+h) - f(x)$ is small for $|x| > \Delta + 1$, but why does it vanish?

Comment: Thanks! I could not find a proper $\varepsilon$-definition of the finiteness of the improper Riemann integral, do you have a recommended book?. Additionally, what is the essence of considering $|h|<1$ (in the second sentence)? When you say by the uniform continuity of $f$ on $[-\Delta-2,\Delta+2]$, do you mean $[-\Delta-1,\Delta+1]$?

Comment: @Bungo I am not saying that $f(x+h)-f(x)$ is small for $|x| >\delta$. If $g(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$ the existence (and finiteness) of  of $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ implies that $g(x)-L \to 0$ (where $L$ is the limit) and this means $\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dt \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Similarly for $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: @Nothingone I am taking $|h|<1$ just to fix some interval in which I can use uniform continuity of $f$. Existence of the improper Riemann  integral simply means $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx$ tends to a finite limit as $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to \infty$. That is all I need for my proof.